# LinearLayout widgets alignment

Tags: android

Full xml goes like this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.brightspot.extrain5psim.view.fragments.NetworthFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fafafa"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some text goes here"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:text="Some text goes here Some text goes here" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#cafafa"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text goes here" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will give the following output.

[image]

If I add the `android:textSize="22sp"` to second `TextView` also I can get the following screen shot.

[image]

Please check the difference between those texts.

My question is why the `TextView` alignment depends on text size of previous `TextView`, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: You have only one child of outer LinearLayout and you are using layout_width :0dp and layout_weight of 1 but to make it work you need to have another child in your outermost LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get rid of the weight sum, I think. You probably don't need it, weight sums are typically calculated automatically.

If this is generated programmatically, then you'll want to use weights. I found in my testing that eliminating the weight sum and then adding weight to both of the text views seems to have fixed the problem you are facing. Without the overall layout, I cannot fully see if this will solve your problem, but it did when I tested and played with just *this* layout configuration (At least as much as I could, obviously I don't have your styles/colors).

Good luck! I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was arising due to layout_width which was set incorrectly with respect to each other ,this code is working fine

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.brightspot.extrain5psim.view.fragments.NetworthFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text goes here "
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="text goes here Some text goes here"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cafafa"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here ,Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here Some text goes here"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text goes here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have used layout_weightSum to set textview properly ,and you can have as many lines as you want

**UPDATED** Shorter implementation :More readable

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.brightspot.extrain5psim.view.fragments.NetworthFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text goes here"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text also goes here and it should be here "
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:text="Some text goes here Some text goes here"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Some text goes here also" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have also implemented this code with the help of only 2 LinearLayout ,If you are interested just say so I will upload that also and if you have confusion regarding this plz ask

Comment: I don't want to split equal space for `TextView`.

Comment: why are you being so picky , Use layout:weightSum wisley to split according to you want to split look some weightSum tutorial, Sorry but this is what I can DO

Comment: I paste your new code It is only showing two textView check it

Comment: I am using nexus 7, In this I got this design only bro.

Comment: Listen I am confused and I don't think I can be any help ,Problem is arising due to complex use of layout thats it , I am pasting sorter 2 LinearLayout code in my answer check it out

Comment: Did you saw `My question is why the TextView alignment depends on text size of previous TextView ` from my question. You test this condition on whatever layout you have created. Test it based on this condition and let me know if it works correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82050/discussion-between-l-x-and-gunaseelan).